# sql trigger consulta sobre la sintaxys

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Hola a todos estoy haciendo un sistema que a los 3 intentos fallidos bloquee el acceso al usuario y tenga que hablar con un Administrador para desbloquearlo y me recomendaron hacerlo con triggers SQL pero no he podido crear una sintaxis valida de momento llevo esto

```
CREATE TRIGGER BLOQUEAR_INTENTOS BEFORE UPDATE ON usuario WHERE intentos = '3' FOR EACH ROW UPDATE usuario SET intentos = '0', bloqueado = '0' WHERE idUsuario = OLD.idUsuario;
```

Agradecería que me ayudaran los que tienen experiencia con sql o que me puedan dar ideas validas de como hacer este sistema en c#

Comment: ¿Revisaste [la](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)?

Comment: ¿Por qué un TRIGGER? ¿Cuál es el contexto donde se podrían producir los intentos fallidos?

Comment: al haber ingresado mal la contraseña tres veces mal, ejemplo en un cajero de un banco